# Prevent constructor being called during deserialization

Tags: c#, serialization

In the constructor of an object I set up a list of strings.

e.g. the list contains "a", "b", "c"

This object gets serialized.

When I deserialize this object the list ends up with the same information twice e.g. "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c"

This is obviously the constructor is called during deserialization and then the serialized object is applied to the object and because it already contains the list items the get added again.

How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: You prevent this by moving the code that sets up that list out of the constructor. But how to do this exactly in your case is a bit hard to guess because your question is missing an [mcve] that demonstrates both usecases of your class.

Comment: I had the same problem and I'm curious what others come up with. I just threw principles (do not create uninitialized objects) over board and defined a public constructor which didn't do anything and was only there for deserialization. Documentation must make clear that it is not intended for the public.

Comment: I mitigated the problems by performing optional initialization in the getters for properties which should best be initialized in the ctor, for example `List<string> Names { get { return _names ?? (_names = init_names() ); } }`.

Comment: What library are you using for serialization?

Comment: .NET serialization (that is, what you get by marking an object `[Serializable]`) solves this by having a custom constructor for deserialization. But it isn't clear from your question what kind of serialization you're using.